# How to make Excel follow a formula algorithm on every 3 rows

Tags: excel, algorithm, if-statement, excel-formula

I want to make Excel follow a formula pattern on every 3 rows, such that after an increase of three in the conditional if statement, there should be an increment of one on return value "TRUE". So that every time I drag it down, the algorithm gets applied to succeeding 3 rows that it follows. I have this simple formula of:

`=IF(B11="RTR",RTR!G11:Z11,IF(B11="DHG2",'DHG2'!G11:Z11,IF(B11="JQV",JQV!G11:Z11,"")))`
`=IF(B12="RTR",RTR!G11:Z11,IF(B12="DHG2",'DHG2'!G11:Z11,IF(B12="JQV",JQV!G11:Z11,"")))`
`=IF(B13="RTR",RTR!G11:Z11,IF(B13="DHG2",'DHG2'!G11:Z11,IF(B13="JQV",JQV!G11:Z11,"")))`
`=IF(B14="RTR",RTR!G12:Z12,IF(B14="DHG2",'DHG2'!G12:Z12,IF(B14="JQV",JQV!G12:Z12,"")))`
`=IF(B15="RTR",RTR!G12:Z12,IF(B15="DHG2",'DHG2'!G12:Z12,IF(B15="JQV",JQV!G12:Z12,"")))`
`=IF(B16="RTR",RTR!G12:Z12,IF(B16="DHG2",'DHG2'!G12:Z12,IF(B16="JQV",JQV!G12:Z12,"")))`

Following the formula I wanted, it's supposed to be followed by:

`=IF(B17="RTR",RTR!G13:Z13,IF(B17="DHG2",'DHG2'!G13:Z13,IF(B17="JQV",JQV!G13:Z13,"")))`

I tried dragging down the formula to apply it to below rows but the pattern doesn't follow to what I wanted. Instead, the row below goes into like:

`=IF(B17="RTR",RTR!G17:Z17,IF(B17="DHG2",'DHG2'!G17:Z17,IF(B17="JQV",JQV!G17:Z17,"")))`

Need a little bit of help here.

Thank you.

Comment: Indirect with a range of cells 3, 6, 9 etc

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. I tried googling how does it function but I couldn't figure it out. Could you give me some examples?

Comment: Check the Excel help or check examples on here. Am on a smartphone so can’t test.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that doesn't require helper cells:

This formula will increment by 1 every 3 rows:

```
=CEILING.MATH(ROW()/3)
```

If you want the sequence to start on a different row, say row 10, you can just subtract that number - 1 from the ROW(), so for starting on row 10 from 1, subtract 9:

```
=CEILING.MATH((ROW()-9)/3)
```

And if you wanted the sequence to start from a different number at a different row, you can just add that number -1 to this whole thing, this example will start at 11 on row 10:

```
=CEILING.MATH((ROW()-9)/3)+10
```

**EDIT:** Much better solution proposed by P.b, you don't need the IFs at all:

```
=INDIRECT(B11 & "!G" & (CEILING.MATH(ROW()/3)+10) & ":Z" & (CEILING.MATH(ROW()/3)+10))
```

Comment: If using INDIRECT I'd drop the multiple IF statements and use `B11` it's value for the sheet name. Otherwise use INDEX (non-volatile) and keep the IF statements.

Comment: `=IF(B11="RTR",INDEX(RTR!G:Z,11+INT((ROW()-11)/3),),etc...)` when using INDEX

Comment: @P.b Thank you, I edited the answer with the shorter INDIRECT version. If you would like to post your own answer I can just delete this.

Comment: I posted a version that's a combination of INDEX with semi-indirect range selection using CHOOSE.

Answer (score 0):

So, an example which you can expand:

[image]

```
VLOOKUP(A1,INDIRECT("'RTR'!"&"G11:Z11",1),1,0)
```

Not sure where you increment of 3 occurs as B11 goes to B12 and even the last two B16 goes to B17 and the target range matches the row numbers.

As I have shown you can build the target range so adding the row numbers is trivial now. They can be taken from cells, C1 could be 3, C2 6 etc.

Answer (score 0):

The following could be used *(to avoid using (volatile) INDIRECT)*:

```
=INDEX(
       CHOOSE( MATCH(B11, {"RTR","DHG2","JQV"}, 0),
               'RTR'!G:Z, 'DHG2'!G:Z, 'JQV'!G:Z),
       INT((ROW()-11)/3)+11,
       )
```

It selects the correct tab by matching the value in `B11` to an array mentioning the names of the tabs. It than indexes range `G:Z` from that tab.

The row number shifts 1 number every 3 rows because of `INT((ROW()-11)/3)+11`.

[image]